# Google sheets: Querying from a pivot table returns #ERROR

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

gOOGLE SHEETS: I am trying to query a value from a Pivot table in a different tab using the below formula.

**query({'RawData Pivot1'!1:1000}, "select * where (Col1 = "A21" and Row2 = 25)")**

However, it gives me an #ERROR.

Please help!

Comment: It's better to show us the error you faced.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(RawData Pivot1'!1:1000); 
 "where Col2 = 25")); 
 "where Col1 = '"&A21&"'")
```